# What does session mean in python?

Tags: python

I have the following code and I need to know what does `self.session = self.connect()` mean?

```
import optparse
import pxssh

class Client:
  def __init__(self, host, user, password):
     self.host =host
     self.user =user
     self.password =password
     self.session =self.connect()

  def connect(self):
     try:
         s =pxssh.pxssh()
         s.login(self.host, self.user, self.password)
         return s
     except Exception, e:
         print e
         print '[-] Error Connecting'
```

Thanks for your help .

Comment: Read the documentation for the modules you're using. (In this case `pxssh`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does " self.session =self.connect() " mean

It calls the object's `connect()` method, and assigns the result to the object's `session` data member.

If you examine the `connect()` method, you'll see that it establishes and returns an `ssh` connection (or `None` if the connection cannot be established).